# JavaScript console.log: How to make the comma param separator use newline for objects instead of space?

Tags: javascript, console.log

When I write something like:

`console.log("data", data);`

where `data` is an object, it'll print "data [some form of the object]" where [some form of the object] is typically a collapsed object with expand arrows that I can click to view the object's elements.

However, this can become painful when the preceding text line is long and there's a lot of output... and I'd rather have that object start on the next line, which makes me either add another `console.log` just for that object, or add a `\n` to the preceding line string.

Since `console.log('whatever', whatever)` appends a space to `'whatever'` when a comma follows it, I'd like some way to specify 'use a newline in this case, or for objects following the comma', but I'm not seeing how to do that.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Maybe try console.table

Answer (score 2):

You need another function that wrapps the `console.log()`,

```js
fancyLog  = function(...args){
    args.forEach( arg=>{
        console.log( arg );
    } );
}
```

this wrapper function will get your task done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use console.dir and the document for it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/dir

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, what you are asking doesn't exist just like that.

You can hack it by doing something like:

```
console.log(`whatever\n${JSON.stringify(whatever, null, 2)}`);
```

Which will print the object in json in the next line. Or if you don't need that, just:

```
console.log(`whatever\n${whatever}`);
```

But it's debatable how much work it really saved from just adding two `console.logs`.

Your final option is to use `console.dir` or `console.table` following that `console.log`, but again it doesn't save you from having to place two lines there.